# How to create multiple Vue components inside of Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue-resource, vue.js

I am using the [togglable tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) component in Bootstrap. I would like a table in each tab. Each one is displaying a table of email logs (Click Event, Open Event, etc). I would also like each table to be loaded dynamically with Vue-resource only once the user clicks on that tab, and for the resource/component to only be loaded once (once we have the data from AJAX, don't refresh it).

How can I set this up? I currently have an `email-table` component and an `email-table-template` template that renders the table, but I'm not sure how to set those up to render themselves when the user clicks the tab, and to only call the AJAX once.

[An illustration of the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXQSp.gif)

Here is my current code for detecting the tab switch and newing up a Vue component:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
var email_event = $(e.target).data('email-event');
switch(email_event) {
  case 'click':
    createClick();
    break;
  // rest of the cases
}

function createClick() {
var click_events = Vue.resource('/api/email_logs/click_events');

click_events.get().then((response) => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#table-click',
    data: {
      searchQuery: '',
      gridColumns: ['campaign_id', 'target_link_name', 'target_link_url', 'created_at'],
      gridData: response.body
    }
  })
});
```

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of what you have tried and where you are getting error.

Comment: Though what you want to achieve is clearly shown in the gif, I feel your question may be too abroad. I'd like to suggest you spend a few hours to go through the official guide and come back with any specific problem you feel hard to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a method only once you can use listen and emit events.

`vm.$once` and `vm.$emit` should do the trick.

Official documentation
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-once

Here is a quick example
https://jsfiddle.net/leocoder/s1nfsao7/4/

Comment: This is what I was looking for, and it also pointed out to me what I need to change fundamentally; I needed to create Vue wrappers for my Bootstrap tabs. So instead of using jQuery and listening for those click normally, I made a Vue wrapper around the tab and used the Vue `v-on:click` directive, and tied that to a call to the AJAX. Your example was super helpful in pointing me in the right direction, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation

> If you want to keep the switched-out components in memory so that you can preserve their state or avoid re-rendering, you can wrap a dynamic component in a `<keep-alive>` element

**Sample**:

`<keep-alive> <component :is="currentView"> <!-- inactive components will be cached! --> </component> </keep-alive>`

In the above example "currentView" is to be set to a component name you want to load/display

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive